# In an Android project, can you use permissions only for select (as opposed to all) flavors?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-advertising-id

My client just got an e-mail from Google Play, saying that once his app starts targeting Android 13 (which hasn't happened yet), we need to use the `AD_ID` permission. And it's an easy one-line addition to AndroidManifest.xml. Problem is, the app has several configurations and one one uses ads and hence needs `AD_ID`. Is there a simple way to use permissions only for some flavors (like free but not premium)?

Comment: "the app has several configurations" -- what specifically do you mean by "configurations" in this context? Do you mean that you only show ads in landscape or something?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I was looking at the wrong keyword, but the app has 2 flavors - free and premium - and I only need that permission in the free version. In the Premium it isn’t needed because that one doesn’t use ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an `AndroidManifest.xml` file in a source set for your free flavor (e.g., `app/src/free/AndroidManifest.xml` for an `app` module). In there, have your `<uses-permission>` element in the proper spot as a child of `<manifest>`, but otherwise leave it empty. That will get merged in with your `main` manifest for `free` builds and will not be included in your `premium` builds.